# UIProgressView height

Tags: ios, uiprogressview

UIProgressView height is different when displayed in iOS 7.0

it's not 9 as the interface builder is showing.

I am trying to transform progressView to increase height. because 9 is too small. and because original size of the progress view is not the same for iOS >= 7.0 and iOS < 7.0. progress view in iOS >= 7.0 is taking more place than supposed to take.

Any ideas how to handle that?

Comment: Didn't you ask this already..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to do this:

```
float systemVersion = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
if (systemVersion >= 7.0){
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0f, 1.2f);// you can change the sy as you want
    yourProgressView.transform = transform;
}
```

Comment: When? I have two cases obviously

Comment: @hasan what do you mean by when? I am saying if you need to increase your progressView height you can play with the transform scale, hope I got you well.

Answer (score 4):

Create CustomProgressView and add following method:

```
- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size {
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width,6);
    return newSize;
}
```

and change number 6 according to your need.